# Can i make a form consisting of different fields with signup fields?

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class employeeModel(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=300,unique=True,help_text='Employee ID should not be same')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail_view',kwargs={'employee_id':self.employee_id})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_id
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Employee Detail'
```

views.py

```
User = get_user_model()
def create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = employeeForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():

            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            User= get_user_model()
            user=
                 User.objects.create_user(
                  username=username,email=email,password=password
                    )
            authenticate(
            request,username=username,email=email,password=password
            )
            user.save()
            form.save()


            return redirect('emp_list')
    else:
        form = employeeForm()
    return render(request,'create_employee.html',{'form':form})
```

Though its not raising any error but User cant create instances though this method, though 'user objects' are showing in EmployeeModel.objects.all() not in User.objects.all(). Thats why when i create any user though this form login fails cause they are not objects of User.

What can i do to make it work? or i have to discard this code?

Answer (score 1):

models.py

```
class employeeModel(models.Model):    
    def __init__(self, employee_id, name, father_name, username, email, password):
        self.employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=300,unique=True,help_text='Employee ID should not be same')
        self.name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        self.father_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        self.username = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
        self.email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
        self.password = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Employee: {}".format(self.name)
```

My suggestion: Try the init method for your employee class as above.

Comment: @ZackAtma So, can i override these fields in form? like for placeholder or for any other attributes ?

Answer (score 1):

@ChidanandaNayak, Yes, though not certain how you intend to use the employeeModel class to create users, make sure all the arguments passed in the class are equivalent to the number of arguments defined in the init method.

Example;

```
id = 123
name = 'John Doe'
father_name = 'Patrick Doe'
username = 'john_doe'
email = 'john_doe@demo.com'
password = '1234567890'
new_user = employeeModel(id, name, father_name, email, password)
```

Comment: But there is the problem arises, so new_user is instance of EmployeeModel not User model? Thats why my login fails.

Comment: Yeah but then where's your User model or the get_user_model() method and create_user() method? The problem might be in those methods.